Where should I place "business logic" when using MongoDB
I'm new to MongoDB.
In one of the answers to this question MongoDB - What about Decimal type of value?, there's a recommendation from Philipp1:

you shouldn't do any business logic on the database anyway, especially not when it's a "dumb" database like MongoDB

I also read that MongoDB is not a transactional database, and transactional operations (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/) should be avoided.
Then my question: where should my business logic be? Something simple as: add $5.00 to the account balance.
Thank you very much!

do it at application level, such as Java/JS/Python... MongoDB do not have features like stored procedure anyway, so it might not be feasible or maintainable if you try to create business logic in database. Another downside is that business logic likely cannot be maintained through version control systems if they are implemented in database level.

Thanks. But in that case, I would need to handle transactional updates?

You already link the official document. If you are looking for single document atomicity, just do the CRUD operation. If you need the multi-documents atomicity, use their transactions API.
